# How to realize a movable controller in iPadOS, like mail APP in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ipados

Mail App in iPad, when we create a new mail, the controller will be presented. But in iPadOS system, this controller can be moved, and if move it to the left side or right side, it can become a multiple window. How Apple to realize this feature?

I try a lot new API about UIViewController but it does not work.

Comment: It's support for multiple scenes - new in iOS 13. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/supporting_multiple_windows_on_ipad and related documentation.

Comment: I can realize the feature with drag and drop API, But in Safari, the multiple tag is easily to drag, it should not press for a long time. How it realize?